# PHP read and execute contents of a file as a string

Tags: php, string, file

I am trying to read a file as a string and return it to the client to be executed as javascript code in order to save it as a variable. Like so

```
<?php
$fileName = 'target.js';
$codeAsString = file_get_contents($fileName);
$script = 'var code=\'' . $codeAsString . '\'';
echo $script;
?>
```

Once returned, I want the variable `code` to have a string representation of the contents of target.js. However, it isn't working. I suspect it has to do with new line characters and single/double quotes... In Python they have a multi line quote

```
"""This
is
a "multi"
line
'quote'
"""
```

Is there anything like this in Javascript/php? I can't even wrap my head around whether I need the single quotes around `$codeAsString` when appending it to `$script`. Do I have to manually go in and prepend backslashes before all quotes, double quotes, back slashes...Surely they have helper functions for this

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_encode is your friend...

```
<?php
$fileName = 'target.js';
$codeAsString = file_get_contents($fileName);
$script = 'var code= '.json_encode($codeAsString) .';';
echo $script;
?>
```

Comment: Nice! That worked almost flawlessly. Except instead of new lines, when I do `console.log()` I get these ghetto little carriage return symbols. Is this specific to Chrome, or does json_encode distinguish between new line and carriage return?

Comment: if I store it in `var code` and do `console.log(code)` the carriage returns are interpretted as new lines. If, however, I store it in an object for whatever reason `{src : ''}` and do `console.log(code)`, now the `src` attribute of `code` has little carriage returns. Therefore, I suspect this is Chrome specific.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP function [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).